# Odoo is not starting

Tags: python, odoo-8

After a database restore (from the production server to the development one) my local odoo server is not starting
I do not have any other error message

```
2016-09-07 16:34:28,737 28304 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0-20150625
2016-09-07 16:34:28,739 28304 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: [u'C:\\Users\\nyulg\\AppData\\Local\\OpenERP S.A.\\Odoo\\addons\\8.0', u'C:\\Users\\nyulg\\Documents\\Projects\\Python\\odoo-8.0\\openerp\\addons', u'C:\\Users\\nyulg\\Documents\\Projects\\Python\\Odoo']
2016-09-07 16:34:28,739 28304 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2016-09-07 16:34:28,739 28304 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2016-09-07 16:34:28,739 28304 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2016-09-07 16:34:28,956 28304 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2016-09-07 16:34:44,471 28304 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2016-09-07 16:34:54,956 28304 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe
2016-09-07 16:35:01,266 28304 INFO ? http: HTTP Configuring static files
2016-09-07 16:35:01,546 28304 INFO None http: Generating nondb routing
2016-09-07 16:35:01,752 28304 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2016 16:35:01] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

the starting parameter has not been changed:

```
-w admin -r odoo --addons-path=C:\Users\nyulg\Documents\Projects\Python\odoo-8.0\openerp\addons,C:\Users\nyulg\Documents\Projects\Python\Odoo
```

Any hint?

Comment: How did you restore the database? Did you do a postgresql restore or an odoo /web/database/manager restore?

Comment: Postgresql restore because /web/database/manager backup and restore works only with local database and in my case we have separated database and application servers

Comment: windows or linux?

Comment: Do you have an odoo filestore on the production server? If so did you bring it to your development server?

Comment: The production server is linux, the development one is Windows. 
I didn't restored the filestore, as I don't need it. 
In the past I've never got this kind of error.

Comment: Could you paste your odoo-server.conf file?